# Solving a nonhomogenous diff eq with variable coefficients

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, problem-solving

I'm trying to understand a linear second order differential equation with variable coefficients:

$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2} = z (1 + z u)$

I already have the solution in an integral form

$u(z) = -\frac{z}{2} \int_0^{\pi/2} d\theta\: \exp(-\frac{z^2}{2}\cos\theta) \sin^{1/2}\theta$.

**My question is**: how do I find this solution? What technique/method to use?

**Bonus question**: What if I add an extra term $z\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$ to the equation, how can I then solve this equation? The modified ode ($C$ is a constant) is

$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial z^2} = z (1 + z u + C \frac{\partial u}{\partial z})$

Comment: What are the boundary conditions?

Comment: Only the following: $\displaystyle{\lim_{z \to \pm\infty}} u(z) = -1/z $, and $u(0)=0$ for the first equation (not involving $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$).

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabolic_cylinder_function

Comment: @Cesareo I've looked at these, and they are in fact the homogenous solutions to my equation. But, 1) I couldn't get the particular solution from these, 2) I do not know how to convert them to the integral form I want to get.